# Problem with scrolling in Recyclerview. Scroll is not smooth

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

This is my code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="Recruitment Responses"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded1"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/frame1"
        android:background="#f9fafc"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The scrolling is not smooth and is quite irritating can something be done to improve this? I want the textview to go up when scrolled upwards along with the Recycler View that is why i have nested both of them in a ScrollView and maybe that is what is creating an issue!

Comment: Nesting views that scroll in the same direction (horizontal/vertical) is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Try using CoordinatorLayout, CollapsibleToolbar to achieve the behavior. Using a recyclerview with height set to `wrap_content` is not a good idea if you have a large set of items.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView> instead of ScrollView solves everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="Recruitment Responses"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded1"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/frame1"
        android:background="#f9fafc"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your activity:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
recyclerView.setScrollView(true);
```

This help you to make `recyclerView` scrollview smooth.

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) to `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`. Do you find any `setScrollView()` method there?

Comment: @Wrichik Basu it is secret